# Save button is missing in the shipping address form at checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout-page

In checkout page when I click on +new address button a popup is shown with a form in it but the save button is missing. How to add the missing save button in the popup form.

Comment: Are you using a custom module in checkout or some kind of customized form validation? as the button should be there by default.

Comment: I am new to magento. I have customised the code now how to revert it back to the default.

Comment: Well hard to say in that way, but if you are using a custom module that make this effect, you can disable the module.
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-enable.html